# Click on class when its hidden in div

Tags: javascript, cypress

`enter code here`im beginner in cypress.

I trying write test. I need click on class "list-button", but when i use :

```
cy.get('.list-button list-button-blue').click() i got syntax error, i use it with .parent() but its syntax error too.


    >   \`\<div class="popupFooter" data-ls-cob-id="38bc"\>\<button
    > onclick="saveAdditionalDataClick()" class="list-button"
    > data-ls-cob-id="38bd"\>Spočítat          přesné ceny\</button\>==$0
    >     
    >     \<button class="list-button list-button-blue" data-fancybox-close data-ls-cob-id="38be"\>Pokračovat s orientačními cenami\</button\>
    > ==$0\`


Thanks for helps guys.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably happening due to selection of class. For these cases, you have to do it as follows:

a. Try to use one class as

```
cy.get('.list-button').click({force:true})
```

or

```
cy.get('.list-button-blue').click({force:true})
```

b. If there are multiple instances of that button you can use order of the button. For example if there are 2 button satisfies your selector and you need to select one you can use (what you write inside "eq" is order of element):

```
cy.get('.list-button-blue').eq(0).click({force:true})
```

or

```
cy.get('.list-button-blue').first().click({force:true})
```

My suggestion is you should deal with your Frontend team and you can put *data-cy* selectors for these elements which is stated as best practice. You can read full description here:https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices

Comment: Hi, thank a lot for hints. This solve my problem.
cy.get('.list-button-blue').first().click({force:true})

Really thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

When you get the message that the element is hidden within another element, you must turn off actionability.

To do this, pass the force parameter to the click command, like this

```js
cy.get('.list-button list-button-blue').click({force:true})
```

You can read the [Actionability guide](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements) for more details on this subject.

Comment: I use it, but i got error Expected to find element: .list-button list-button-blue, but never found it.